# How to realize fixed-top menu on Bootstrap with left and right indentation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need this menu to be always on the top with constant indentation from left and right sides of the page:
[image]

Now it's been done with JQuery this way:

```
$('.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top').css('width', (parseInt($('.col-xs-8.col').width()) + parseInt($('.col-xs-4.col').width()) + parseInt($('.col-xs-4.col').css('padding-left')) + parseInt($('.col-xs-4.col').css('padding-right')) + parseInt($('.col-xs-8.col').css('padding-left'))).toString() + 'px');
$('.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top').css('left', (parseInt($('.col-xs-8.col').offset().left) + parseInt($('.col-xs-8.col').css('padding-left'))).toString() + 'px');
```

But it doesn't work properly when I change the scale of the page:
[image]

So how could I solve this problem by using just Bootstrap (maybe some less parameter) without using JS at all?

The HTML code of the menu:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Меню</span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;" src="http://elcode.ru/images/logo.png"/></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/news">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hotline</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
    </div>
```

Comment: it's slightly unclear what you want to achieve... do you just want it to have 1 indentation from the left that is kept always?

Comment: I need this menu always on top with width of 12 columns what I use for articles and anouncements below but without stretching on all window size when this menu has fixed position.

Comment: sorry, that didn't help a lot, do you want the menu to stretch?

Comment: No, I need to keep the menu's width in proportion to the col-xs-8 + col-xs-4 below just like here: http://www.cossa.ru/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap - full width navbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085962/twitter-bootstrap-full-width-navbar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How i understand you do not need any JS here, pure Bootstrap is enough.

I made a small sample on codepen - http://codepen.io/tanotify/pen/BsxHA
I added to header .container to add width

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div class="navbar container navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

Comment: i don't see a difference between your solution and the way it appears to happen in the OP's case, can you clarify what you believe you fixed with this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it simply with css.

```
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top{ width : 100%; position: fixed;}
```

this will be left to right with the change of screen resolution